# how to setup different toolbar using navigation controller component?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I am actually not sure, how the correct way or the best practice to set different toolbar using navigation controller component

in my app. I want to set 2 different toolbars.

1. green toolbar
2. red toolbar

two toolbars with different colour. this is just to simplify the case, actually I have multiple toolbars

I am using navigation controller component. and currently on my Main Activity as the host, I set the green toolbar in my main activity using this code

```
        setSupportActionBar(green_toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

        // set up top hierarchy destination
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.destination_home,
            R.id.destination_search,
            R.id.destination_user_control,
            R.id.destination_create_event)
        )

        green_toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
```

so what is the best way to set different toolbar using navigation controller component ?

do I have to make those 2 different toolbars in my main activity? or do I have to set fragmentY destination(that has red toolbar) as another activity not as the fragment ?

or.... I don't know....please help :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The answer below is for an app that use Bottom Navigation View, if you are using Navigation Drawer then use [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64220719/9101876)

so according the documentation from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#support_app_bar_variations) , I need to set the toolbar in each fragment.

> If, however, your top app bar changes substantially across
> destinations, then consider removing the top app bar from your
> activity and defining it in each destination fragment, instead.

so we will add the toolbar in each fragment instead of set it in MainActivity. if you set toolbar in each fragment, it also will make it possible to implement Collapsing Toolbar.

say for example in your bottom navigation menu you have home, profile and search fragments as top level fragment (root) like this

[image]

so in **EACH** top level fragment set the toolbar using this code in `onViewCreated` of your fragment.

```
val toolbar = view.findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbarInYourFragment)
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
    R.id.destination_home,
    R.id.destination_profile  // set all your top level destinations in here
    R.id.destination_search)
)

val navHostFragment = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navHostFragment,appBarConfiguration)
```

you have to pass `appBarConfiguration` to remove back button in your toolbar. so you have to pass `appBarConfiguration` in each top level fragment (home,search,profile), not only in your home.

and for the rest of the fragments you don't need to pass `appBarConfiguration`, so for the rest of your fragments just pass this code in `onViewCreated` .

```
val toolbar = view.findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbarInYourFragment)
val navHostFragment = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navHostFragment)
```

and if your toolbar has menu, then add this code:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)

(activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { view ->
    view.findNavController().navigateUp()
}
```

to use `AppBarConfiguration` class , in gradle app you need to use `navigation-ui-ktx` artifact and you need to add compile options and kotlin options like this

```
android {
   

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

}


dependencies {

    def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha04"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
}
```

don't forget to add noActionBar in your res value style xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">


        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


    </style>
```

Comment: Did you observe the toolbar of each fragment doing a sort of flash/blink when switching between fragments when doing this? I'm using this code and the toolbar flashes all the time.

Comment: @schv09 in my case, no, there is no blink at all

Comment: Thanks, @Alexa289; that's cool. I ended up using a single toolbar in the main activity because I couldn't get the flashing to stop.

Comment: This worked perfectly, now I am having another problem, I have drawerLayout and drawer icon is not showing when using the above steps, since no toolbar in the main activity how to get the drawer icon. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @WIT_NGU use this answer if you are using Navigation Drawer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64220719/9101876

Comment: casting to a particular activity can be problematic especially when testing the fragment in isolation, I suggest you safe cast

Comment: If you are getting blinking using @Alexa289's answer, it's most likely caused by default animations. Mine was from fading animations between fragments. If you override your bottom navigation tab's setOnItemSelectedListener, you can navigate to each tab without triggering any animations.

Comment: This won't work in multi-setup project. You need to have a separate module having all the nav_graphs visible to each other and then you can have such solution.

Answer (score 9):

use the code below if your app using Navigation Drawer, if you are using Bottom Navigation View, then use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61094072/9101876)

first, you have to remove the toolbar from MainActivity, and you have to set the toolbar in each your fragment xml. if you set toolbar in each fragment, it also will make it possible to implement Collapsing Toolbar. from the documentation in [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#support_app_bar_variations), it is said

> If, however, your top app bar changes substantially across
> destinations, then consider removing the top app bar from your
> activity and defining it in each destination fragment, instead.

remove the toolbar from your MainActivity. set your MainActivity xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graph" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

for example, my app will be like this

[image]

it has 3 top level destinations: message, chat and share

then set your MainActivity like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var navController : NavController
    lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.destination_share,
            R.id.destination_message, // set all your top level destinations in here
            R.id.destination_chat), // don't forget the parentheses
            drawer_layout // include your drawer_layout
        )


        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    }


    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController,appBarConfiguration)
    }

    
}
```

in **EACH** top level fragment, set it using the code below

```
class ChatFragment : Fragment() { // for Message and Share Fragment, will be the same

    lateinit var mActivity : FragmentActivity

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        activity?.let { mActivity = it }

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        setUpToolbar()
        
    }

    private fun setUpToolbar() {

        val mainActivity = mActivity as MainActivity

        mainActivity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
        val appBarConfiguration = mainActivity.appBarConfiguration
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration)

    }


}
```

and in the child fragment, i.e if you want to show back button instead of hamburger button in your fragment, then use the same code as above, except the `setToolbar` method will be different, like this

```
private fun setUpToolbar() {

        val mainActivity = mActivity as MainActivity
        val navigationView: NavigationView = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.navigation_view)

        mainActivity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(mainActivity,navController)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navController)

    }
```

and if your toolbar has menu, then add this code in `setToolbar` method:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { view ->
    view.findNavController().navigateUp()
}
```

to use `AppBarConfiguration` class , in gradle app you need to use `navigation-ui-ktx` artifact and you need to add compile options and kotlin options like this

```
android {
   

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

}


dependencies {

    def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha04"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
}
```

don't forget to add noActionBar in your res value style xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">


        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


    </style>
```

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorogeOdongo unfortunately I can only read Java. feel free if you want to convert it to Java

Comment: I totally dont know Kotlin is it okay if your can just read it in java file form i will understand

Answer (score 1):

It whould be more convenient to leave MainActivity layout with just navigation fragment and define needed toolbars in fragments layouts.
Then in each fragment `onCreateView`:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { view ->
    view.findNavController().navigateUp()
}
```

For better example see how this is done in Android-Sunflower app by google:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower

Comment: in my case, I need to set AppBarConfiguration that related to the toolbar on the mainactivity. so thats why I need set the toolbar from the main activity

Comment: @Pavel what is the function of  navigateUp on setNavigationOnClickListener ? does it make my all toolbar clickable and make it back ? or is it just make to set the back button ?

Answer (score 0):

You must set separate toolbar on each fragments, but it a little bit confusing. I used library for solving this problem.

Use the navigation component in the same way. For every fragments do this.

Create toolbar in layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="?colorPrimary"
            android:text="Next fragment"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And use 'setupToolbar' method in fragment

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_first) {

    ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupToolbar(toolbar)
    }  

    ...

}
```

and don't forget to implement lib on your dependencies, but be careful this lib isn't on 
release version, and may be changed.

```
repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.AlexanderGuru:MultipleToolbars:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

details: https://github.com/AlexanderGuru/MultipleToolbars

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the outcome I wanted using parts of the answers above.

I left the nav drawer code in the main activity and the toolbar code in the main xml, then modified the setUpToolbar() function as follows...

```
private fun setUpToolbar() {
    val mainActivity = mActivity as MainActivity
    val toolbar = requireView().findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.settings_toolbar)    
    val navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
    val appBarConfiguration = mainActivity.appBarConfiguration

    mainActivity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)  
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration)
}
```